# Photoshop Javascript image not rendering on screen before alert box displayed

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I am brand new here and a novice at scripting.  I am putting together a script for our image processing team with a component that asks the user to confirm the foreground and background colors before closing the document. 
The issue I can't seem to get past is the script is processing all the functions with the alert written at the end however the final image the user is supposed to see to verify with the alert box is not rendering before the alert box pops up and pauses the code. A sample of the full code is below. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
#target photoshop
app.bringToFront();
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var selRefMain = docRef.selection;
checkColors();

function checkColors() 
    docRef.resizeImage(800, 800, 72, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC); 
    var selBoundsFg = Array(Array(0, 0), Array(800, 800), Array(0, 800)); //creates bounds for Foreground color selection
    var selBoundsBg = Array(Array(0, 0), Array(800, 800), Array(800, 0));//creates bounds for background color selection
    selRefMain.select (selBoundsFg);
    selRefMain.fill(app.foregroundColor);
    selRefMain.select (selBoundsBg);
    selRefMain.fill(app.backgroundColor);
    selRefMain.deselect();
};
alert ("Please check Foredround and Background colors");
```

Comment: At a guess I'd say the time to fill the image takes longer to draw than the time to process the code so the alert is being shown first. I don't think there is a redraw() function, but you could put in an artificial delay instead.

Comment: I've tried using the $.sleep(300); function to delay the alert box, but the image remains unrendered (all black) until after the alert box is acknowledged.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to wait for a redraw:

```
var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
desc.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID("Stte"), charIDToTypeID("Stte"), charIDToTypeID("RdCm"));
executeAction(charIDToTypeID("Wait"), desc, DialogModes.NO);
```

This is pulled from line 8273 of [stdlib.js](http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html).